Why can't I reassign flexible array member?
I have the following struct with a flexible array member. However, the code does not compile:
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 5

typedef struct Object {
   int size;
   int elements[];
} Object;

int main(void) {
  Object* result = calloc(1, sizeof(Object) + sizeof(int)*INITIAL_CAPACITY);
  if (result == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_CAPACITY; i++) {
    result->elements[i] = 1;
  }

  result->size = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  int new_size = 2*result->size;
  int* new_elements = calloc(1, sizeof(int)*new_size);
  if (new_elements == NULL) {
     return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_CAPACITY; i++) {
    result[i].entries->key = -1;
  }

  result->elements = new_elements; // "error: expression must be modifiable lvalue"
}

Why can't I reassign the flexible array member to a new, larger array?
ps- it compiles if I change the flexible array member to instead read int* elements but I'm not sure why...

You allocated the whole structure, not just the array. You need to use realloc() to enlarge the whole thing.

And if you want to zero out the extra space created by realloc(), you will have to use memset on the region between the old size and the new size.

Arrays are not modifiable lvalues as pointed out in the error message, so you cannot assign to them. Even if you could do it, the value you are trying to assign to the array is not an array, it's a pointer.

A flexible array member is not a pointer, it's part of the original struct. Since you allocated the struct dynamically, you need to use realloc() to enlarge it.
#define INITIAL_CAPACITY 5

typedef struct Object {
   int size;
   int elements[];
} Object;

int main(void) {
  Object* result = calloc(1, sizeof(Object) + sizeof(int)*INITIAL_CAPACITY);
  if (result == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  result->size = INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  int new_size = 2*result->size;
  Object* new_obj = realloc(result, sizeof(Object) + sizeof(int)*new_size);
  if (new_obj == NULL) {
     return;
  }
  result = new_obj;
  // zero out the new allocation, like calloc does
  memset(&new_obj->elements[result->size], 0, sizeof(int)*(new_size - result->size));
  result->size = new_size;
}


Might also need to zero out the region between the old size and the new size, since OP was using calloc.

I've added mention of this, but left the actual implementation as an exercise.

Something like memset(&new_obj->elements[result->size], 0, sizeof(int)*(new_size - result->size)); before result->size = new_size;.

Just realized that their original code doesn't just zero out the new allocation, it also replaces the old allocation with zeroes.

True, although they didn't actually change any of the elements to be non-zero before the resize. :-)

"A flexible array member is not a pointer, it's part of the original struct". Thanks- this clarifies a lot.

Obviously this is an over simplification, since they never even use the structure or array. @IanAbbott

@Barmar Doesn't the flexible array member decay to int* elements?

Yes. But decaying only happens when using an array as an r-value, not an l-value.

@testing09 "Doesn't the flexible array member decay to int* elements?" Not when it is the left operand of an assignment operator.

@IanAbbott @Barmar  I have added a little bit more code, where I set each array element to 1 (not using memcpy on purpose). What is happening here? Is it a struct that has a int pointer (elements) to a contiguous block of memory that holds an array of integers OR is it a struct that within it i.e. no pointer, a contiguous block of memory that holds the integers?  Also is my code not idiomatic i.e. sold I b using int* elements instead of the flexible array member since I want to resize? I would need to explicitly allocate the array- in this case, I could use calloc rather than memset.

It's just like a struct that ends with an array. The only difference is that the size of the array isn't declared. It uses the extra memory after the end of the structure that was allocated by malloc()

@testing09 It is up to the programmer to decide whether a flexible array member or a pointer is most appropriate for a particular use case.

Flexible arrays are arrays. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not assign one array to another array.
Moreover you at first allocated memory for a whole object of the structure type including its flexible array. The new allocated memory is not contained in the extent of memory allocated for the object. So in any case your approach is wrong.
